# Auto-crop the image, and extract the area of interest from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, yolo

I want to *crop* image automatically, it means I don't want to specify the *pixels* or *coordinates* each time, the module/code which should detect the object (i.e. area of interest) and extract it from an image.

Or there is any ***algorithm*** to crop desired part from image (Area of Interest)
[for example my image contains two part one is white and other is in RGB form, but I want only the RGB form part from complete image].

I have also tried below code, but it was not helpful.

```
from PIL import Image
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.morphology import convex_hull_image
im = imread('L_2d.jpg')
plt.imshow(im)
plt.title('input image')
plt.show()
# create a binary image
im1 = 1 - rgb2gray(im)
threshold = 0.5
im1[im1 <= threshold] = 0
im1[im1 > threshold] = 1
chull = convex_hull_image(im1)
plt.imshow(chull)
plt.title('convex hull in the binary image')
plt.show()
imageBox = Image.fromarray((chull*255).astype(np.uint8)).getbbox()
cropped = Image.fromarray(im).crop(imageBox)
cropped.save('L_2d_cropped.jpg')
plt.imshow(cropped)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please explain your question properly with images if possible of the input and the output you received and the issue you are facing.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Please re-read it, check it and [edit] it. Please show, and clearly identify, what you start with and what you expect as a result. Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to crop the PCB ROI? Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold, create morph rect kernel, dilate to combine into single contour, find contours, and sort from largest to smallest (largest ROI should be the PCB), find bounding rectangle, then crop using Numpy slicing

Comment: @RahulKedia I have edited my question, if you could able to understand my question now, please guide me.